# How do I finish solving $f(x)f(2y)=f(x+4y)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I'm trying to solve this functional equation:
$$f(x)f(2y)=f(x+4y)$$

The first thing I tried was to set $x=y=0$; then I get:
$$f(0)f(0)=f(0)$$
which means that either $f(0)=0$ or we can divide the equation by $f(0)$ and then $f(0)=1$.

Case 1: If $f(0)=0$ then we can try to set $x=0$. Then;
$$f(0)f(2y)=f(4y)$$
$$0=f(4y)$$
Which means that one of the solutions is a constant function $f(x)=0$

Case 2: If $f(0)=1$. This is where I'm stuck.

I tried to set $x=0$, then I get:
$$f(2y)=f(4y)$$
I also tried to set $x=-4y$. Then I get:
$$f(-4y)f(2y)=f(0)=1$$

I think that these two observations could be useful, but I don't know how to continue from here. I have guessed that another solution is $f(x)=1$ but I don't know how to show that there aren't any others as well.

Comment: Are you looking for continuous solutions.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I'm supposed to find.

Comment: In your last equalities, replace $ f(2)$ by $f(2y)$

Comment: You should always mention what is the domain and codomain of said function (based on the computations you make it seems it is $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$). Same applies also for domain of the variables in the equation itself, $x,y$ in this case (again it seems those can be any real numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $ f(0)=1$, you got

for $ y\in \Bbb R $,
$$f(4y)=f(2y)=f(y)=f(\frac y2)$$
$$=...=f(\frac{y}{2^n})$$
for each $ n\ge 0$.

but by continuity of $ f $ at $ 0$,
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f(\frac{y}{2^n})=f(0)=1$$

thus
$$(\forall y\in \Bbb R)\;\; f(y)=1$$

Answer (score 5):

When solving functional equations, we aren't able to claim continuity and other such properties. We in fact don't need the continuity condition in order to solve the problem.

For the $f(0)=1$ case, we can reuse some of your claims:

(1)$$f(2y)=f(4y)$$

(2)$$f(-4y)f(2y)=1$$

We can substitute 1) into 2) to get that

(3)$$f(-4y)f(4y)=1. $$

We now plug $y=-\frac{x}{2}$ into our original equation to get another identity:

(4)$$f(x)f(-x)=f(-x).$$

We can replace $4y$ with $x$ and combine (3) with (4):

$$f(-x)=f(x)f(-x)=f(4y)f(-4y)=1.$$

We get $f(-x)=1$, and we can flip the sign of the $-x$ to get that

$f(x)=1$ for all x

Answer (score 3):

Ryan's answer is showing how to finish the argument you are making. This answer provides alternative way to solve the equation without splitting into the cases in the first place.

Substituting $y/2$ in place of $y$, we get functional equation $f(x)f(y)=f(x+2y)$, which is little more symmetric. If we now swap $x$ and $y$, we get $f(x+2y)=f(y+2x)$. Put $y=-2x$ and observe that $f(-3x)=f(0)$. Finally, substitute $-x/3$ in place of $x$ and get $f(x)=f(0)$, hence $f(x)$ is a constant function. Let $f(x)=a$, putting into the original equation this gives $a^2=a$, so $a=0$ or $a=1$. Thus $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$ are the only solutions.